# Regarding SQLite replication

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am working with SQLite in C++ on Linux. I want to replicate the SQLite database in another machine. I want to read the SQLite database file using `fstream` and create a copy in the other machine.

My code :

```
 ifstream _fstream;
_fstream.open("Sourcefile",ios::in); 
 ofstream _ostream;
_ostream.open("ReplicatedFile",ios::out);
_ostream << _fstream;
_ostream.close();
_fstream.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the built in [SQLite Backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) which allows for online backup of the database. This could be used to create a form of replication, you would of course have to move the file to a remote location yourself (if desired). It is probably best to use the `sqlite_backup_*()` functions rather than directly accessing the file(s), since the sqlite functions will lock the database.

Comment: yeah...as you said , i am using backup apis to create backup. After creating backup , i want to move the backup file to remote location. for that i am trying to use io streams class. can you help me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but if you need to do the replication across multiple servers (distributed), [Rqlite](https://github.com/otoolep/rqlite) might be suited for you.

> rqlite is a distributed relational database, which uses SQLite as its storage engine. rqlite uses Raft to achieve consensus across all the instances of the SQLite databases, ensuring that every change made to the system is made to a quorum of SQLite databases, or none at all.

You can read more here:
http://www.philipotoole.com/replicating-sqlite-using-raft-consensus/